# How map values using 2 conditions when there is duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, concatenation

### How to make cost attribution based in 2 conditions (month and id).

#### The problem is.. id repeats for every month, but cost are different for every month

so how to map these values from reff table to the main dataframe by 2 conditions(id and month)

There are duplicates overall but not duplicates in the some month.

Sample of my data

```
cw=

  adgroup    Date    
  1001   2018-08-01
  1001   2019-03-01
  1003   2018-03-01
  1002   2018-03-01
  1001   2018-05-01
  1003   2018-08-01
  1001   2019-12-12
  1002   2019-03-01
  1001   2019-08-01
```

Reff table

```
f_spend=


    adgroup   Month        cost  

    1001    2019/08     101,1
    1002    2019/08      70,1
    1003    2019/03    4221,1
    1001    2018/05     101,1
    1002    2018/03      50,1
    1003    2018/08    8221,1
    1001    2019/08    5401,1
    1002    2019/08      50,1
    1003    2019/12    9221,1
    1001    2019/08     101,1
    1002    2019/08      50,1
    1003    2019/12    6221,1
```

What I done

```
# grouping by the main data( facebook data) by id

cw["id"].replace(to_replace=[None], value=np.nan, inplace=True)

grouped_cw = cw.groupby(["adgroup"]).sum()
grouped_cw = pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw)



# merging two tables together

f_spend = f_spend.merge(grouped_cw, left_on='adgroup', right_index=True)
f_spend["cost"] = pd.to_numeric(f_spend["cost"])



# mapping values to original data
cw['spent'] = cw['adgroup'].map(f_spend.set_index('adgroup')['cost'])
```

## Doesnt work because I've duplicates, but I should not drop them

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for this part of your code:

```
# merging two tables together
f_spend = f_spend.merge(grouped_cw, left_on='adgroup', right_index=True)
f_spend["cost"] = pd.to_numeric(f_spend["cost"])

# mapping values to original data
cw['spent'] = cw['adgroup'].map(f_spend.set_index('adgroup')['cost'])
```

You shouldn't be using adgroup, you should be using your Month/Date columns to perform the join, because the date is the part of your data which is unique for each event.

Comment: the problem is if I join by Date, I cant group the total by id's to then map